# Build a grouped JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am building a Rails/Backbone app and I will show users in a table.
I want to create a JSON tree which is grouped on the user ID/Name.

**This is how it looks now**

```
[{
    "total_entries": 2
},
{
    "entries": [{
            "id": 21,
            "status": "pending",
            "starts_at_date": "2018-02-02",
            "starts_at_time": "12:00",
            "ends_at_date": "2018-02-02",
            "ends_at_time": "12:00",
            "description": "",
            "ttype": "vacation",
            "sum": 0,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "fullname": "Marcus Lurem"
            },
            "timetype": null,
            "pause": 0,
            "can_manage": true
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "status": "pending",
            "starts_at_date": "2018-02-07",
            "starts_at_time": "12:00",
            "ends_at_date": "2018-02-07",
            "ends_at_time": "12:00",
            "description": "",
            "ttype": "doctor",
            "sum": 0,
            "user": {
                "id": 2,
                "fullname": "Anna Palmgren"
            },
            "timetype": null,
            "pause": 0,
            "can_manage": true
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I need it to be grouped on the name.

This is how I build the JSON object now.

```
json.array! [0,1] do |index|
  if index == 0
    json.total_entries @total
  else
    json.entries @events do |event|
      json.extract! event, :id, :starts_at_date, :starts_at_time, :ends_at_date, :ends_at_time, :description, :ttype
            json.sum event.sum
            json.user event.user, :id, :fullname
            json.can_manage true
        end
  end
end
```

**Update**

Should look like this more or less.

- Marcus Lurem

  - Id
  - Status
  - starts_at_date
  - description
- Anna Palmgren

  - Id
  - Status
  - starts_at_date
  - description

Comment: What do you mean by "I need it to be grouped on the name" ? Can you add more details?

Comment: Have you tried starting from `@events.group_by(&:id)`? Perhaps pop an example of your desired output in the question?

Comment: There are now two users. I want to group the reports on each person. So first row is the name and then all the reports belonging to that name/user and then the next name with their reports and so on.

Comment: @JonathanClark Can you update the question what `json` actually contains here `json.array! [0,1] do |index|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
json.entries @events.group_by(&:user) do |user, events|
  json.user :id, :fullname
  json.events events do |event|
    json.extract! event, :id, :starts_at_date, :starts_at_time, :ends_at_date, :ends_at_time, :description, :ttype
  end
end
```